# Function passed as props not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-props

I am trying to pass a function named addtodo as a props from a class. I have passed the function as below

```
export class Todo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {todos:[]};

        this.addtodo = this.addtodo.bind(this);
        this.deleteTodo = this.deleteTodo.bind(this);

      }
    componentDidMount(){
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(res=>{
    this.setState({
       todos:res.data

    })
})
    }
  addtodo(todo){
        todo.id=Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
        todo.completed=true
       const todos=[...this.state.todos,todo]
       this.setState({
         todos:todos
       })
         }
    deleteTodo(id){
        const todo=this.state.todos.filter(todo=>{
         return(
            todo.id!==id
         )
        }
            )
            this.setState({
                todos:todo
            })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
           <h1 className="center-align"> Todos</h1>
                   <Todolist todos={this.state.todos} deleteTodo={this.deleteTodo}/>
                   <Addtodo addtodo={this.addtodo}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Todo
```

And in Addtodo.js, I am using the function as props as below

```
 class Addtodo extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { title:'',
    body:''
};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

  }

handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
        [e.target.id]:[e.target.value]
    })
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        this.props.addtodo(this.state)
        this.setState({
            title:'',
            body:''
        })
        }


    render() {
        return (
            <form className="col s12" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="input-field col s6">
                <input placeholder="Add title" id="title" type="text" className="validate" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
              </div>
              <div className="input-field col s6">
                <input placeholder="Add body" id="body" type="text" className="validate" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
              </div>
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </div>
              </form>
        )
    }
}

export default Addtodo
```

But I am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.addtodo is not a function`. I checked for spelling error as well but could not get why this is not working. Whereas if I pass it as a props to another class and simply log a hello message it is working.

Comment: I don't know the rest of the code, but it might be because you didn't add the function "addtodo" to the class where you're declaring it, thus this.addtodo does not exist.

Comment: can you add the full code for the parent component? that would help addressing the issue.

Comment: I have added the function to the class Todo.js and the first piece of code I have posted is the same declaration

Comment: Read my answer below, you are missing registring the function in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully run your code on the stackblitz, and there are no errors

and i found another bug,

before

```js
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: [e.target.value]
    });
  }
```

after

```js
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  }
```

[check stackblitz demo](https://react-wmvx6v.stackblitz.io)

tip:
Because i don't have enough points, so i cannot add comments, can only editor answer

update:

before:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="container">
        <Addtodo />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Todo} />
          <Route path="/:id" component={Task} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="container">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Todo} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Please check the code is not more than one Addtodo ?

Comment: It is not working for me. I am getting the same error everytime.

Comment: can u make stackblitz demo ?

Comment: i check you stackblitz demo, and find  is not more than one Addodo component, so maybe u can check u code on u computer @octobercms

Answer (score 0):

You're not registering the function `addtodo` in the class, thus `this.addtodo` is not bound to your function `addtodo` but instead to null. Hence your error.

See this example from [React docs - Handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html):

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Notice on line 6 the function is first bound to the class, then it can be defined and called through `this.<function_name>`.

In your code you're missing in the constructor:

```
this.addtodo = this.addtodo.bind(this);
```

Until so, you cannot call `this.addtodo`, for it's not bound to `this`, thus your error that `this.props.addtodo` is not a function.

Comment: I have used arrow function. I added the rest of my code so, can you please check it.

Comment: You're missing the this.addtodo = this.addtodo.bind(this);

Comment: I'd suggest adding the explicit constructor(props) to your class. And in there, place your state under this.state, and this addtodo bind.

Comment: Can you update your code above with that, so I can double check the rest?

Anyways, it's good code style to make your constructor explicit like that, so don't remove it.

Comment: My second suggestion is to add ";" and the line endings, JS can mess itself up. In working code I wouldn't care about it, but as I cannot run your code, adding the semicolons will help making sure it's not due to some improper parsing of the code.

Comment: Please check my updated code. I could not get what went wrong since the delete function is working as expected but the add function is not working

Comment: Can you also post the code of AddTodo class? The problem might be on that side. I'd say it requires the constructor do be defined just like this one, through constructor(props) {...}.

Comment: Done please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing binding in your constructor I guess. In your constructor, you need to declare it like this

```
this.addtodo = this.addtodo.bind(this);
```

Edited **

I have tested the code and seems like there was no error,

Todo.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Addtodo from "./Addtodo";

export class Todo extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: [],
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        todos: res.data,
      });
    });
  }
  addtodo = (todo) => {
    todo.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    todo.completed = true;
    const todos = [...this.state.todos, todo];
    this.setState({
      todos: todos,
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.todos);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="center-align"> Todos</h1>
        <Addtodo addtodo={this.addtodo} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Todo;
```

Addtodo.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class Addtodo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { title: "", body: "" };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: [e.target.value],
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addtodo(this.state);
    this.setState({
      title: "",
      body: "",
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="col s12" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="input-field col s6">
            <input
              placeholder="Add title"
              id="title"
              type="text"
              className="validate"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="input-field col s6">
            <input
              placeholder="Add body"
              id="body"
              type="text"
              className="validate"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Addtodo;
```